# How to get HTTP response body i.e. download using BackgroundUploader

Tags: http, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, download

I need to upload a file to a server which is not in my control using Windows Phone 8.1.

After the upload of file is done, the server sends the link for the uploaded file in the body of the 200 OK response of HTTP.

To handle background scenarios of Windows Phone, want to run a Background Uploader to upload the file and once done need to **get the body of the HTTP 200 OK which has the link for the uploaded file**.

However going in the straight forward way not getting any solution for this.

If someone has some way to get this done, would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

If you have some body in the response then you can try something like this:

```
var request = new BackgroundTransferRequest(targetUri)
{
    DownloadLocation = new Uri(downloadTo, UriKind.Relative),
    UploadLocation = new Uri(uploadFrom, UriKind.Relative),
    Method = "POST"
};
```

Here, your response will be written to the file created in DownloadLocation path.

Also, in WP8.1, I think they have the direct support for accessing the response in background uploader. You can try it out:

```
ResponseInformation response = upload.GetResponseInformation();
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in response.Headers)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Header: {0}, Value: {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
            }
```

where upload is:

```
        BackgroundUploader uploader = new BackgroundUploader();
        UploadOperation upload = await uploader.CreateUploadAsync(uri, parts);
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `BackgroundUploader` in Windows Phone Runtime (WP8.1 RT XAML), you must have attached a progress callback function, which is invoked in the background.

In this function, the response received can be handled as:

```
private void UploadProgress(UploadOperation upload)
        {
            BackgroundUploadProgress progress = upload.Progress;

            if (progress.HasResponseChanged)
            {
                // We've received new response headers & body from the server.
                using (var inputStream = upload.GetResultStreamAt(0))
                    {
                        using (StreamReader tr = new StreamReader(inputStream.AsStreamForRead()))
                        {
                            string respBody = tr.ReadToEnd();
                            //Handle this response string.
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
```

Hope this works for you.

Although it is an year old question, this might help someone else.